# How to create button with linear gradient border, rounded corners and transparent background?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I would like to create border with linear gradient border, rounded corners and **transparent background**.

I have:

```css
.btn-gradient-1 {
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, darkorchid) 1;
}

.btn-gradient-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box, linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, darkorchid) border-box;
  border-radius: 50em;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn-gradient-1">Button One</button>
  <button class="btn-gradient-2">Button Two</button>
</div>
```

Problem is that `linear-gradient` not accept `transparent` color value. Is there any hack? **The button must have transparent background**.

https://jsfiddle.net/c3ogjrzh/

Answer (score -1):

To add transparency, we use the `rgba()` function to define the color stops. The last parameter in the `rgba()` function can be a value from 0 to 1, and it defines the transparency of the color: 0 indicates full transparency, 1 indicates full color (no transparency).

Your transparency will start from `darkblue` (0 0 153) to `darkorchid` (153 50 204)

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,153,0), rgba(153,50,204,1))
```

```css
.btn-gradient-1 {
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, darkorchid) 1;
}
 
.btn-gradient-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) padding-box,
              linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,153,0), rgba(153,50,204,1)) border-box;
  border-radius: 50em;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
 
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn-gradient-1">Button One</button>
  <button class="btn-gradient-2">Button Two</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The background of button must be transparent (red in example, but in general transparent)